# iTunes Connect Prerelease – What happens if I remove users who are also internal testers?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, beta

We want to be able to make our app available to some users on short notice. Hence, we want to add them as iTunes Connect users and make them internal users of the build we've uploaded.

Is it possible to remove these users immediately after they've installed the build? Will it affect the installation on their phone?

Are there any other options without having to go through beta review, i.e. quick options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go through the beta review.  It generally only take a few hours for the first version and then if you don't have significant changes all future ones go through immediately.  I have been using it with external testers and it has worked really well for quick turn around.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to add them to iTunes Connect.
Just send them the mail an existing user got from the system, this will enable everybody to install the app!

I enabled our QA team to be able to test without adding everybody to iTunes Connect with ridiculous rights on the platform.

Comment: This didn't work for me – upon forwarding the e-mail, the button "Open in Testflight" seems to disappear

Comment: That's strange - will double check if it worked due to a special setup - thanks for the heads up!